# How to Integrate STSADM command within Windows Form App

Tags: 2007, development, migration, stsadm, .net

I am developing a Windows Form Application which will have one option as "Export a Site" and another to "Import a Site" I want it to be done using following STSADM commands but not sure what I need to add in button click event (C#) so that it will execute a STSADM command.

> stsadm.exe -o export -url https://abc20.dev.com/cl/asdjsa/default.aspx 
>   -filename C:\Export.cab -includeusersecurity -versions 4 –overwrite

**Edit** this worked for me

```
Process exportSite = new Process();

string commonFilesPath = System.Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.CommonProgramFiles);
string commandLine = " -o export -url " + SPContext.Current.Web.Url + " -filename c:\\" + tempName + ".exp -overwrite -includeusersecurity";

exportSite.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = true;
exportSite.StartInfo.FileName = commonFilesPath + @"\Microsoft Shared\web server extensions\12\BIN\" + "stsadm.exe ";
exportSite.StartInfo.Arguments = commandLine;
exportSite.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
exportSite.Start();
exportSite.Close();
```

Comment: I know this is not what you asked for, but you should rather use powershell. STSADM is dying very quickly. Also, why not just use the Microsoft.SharePoint.dll directly in your winforms app? Make sure you set your compiler to compile it as 64 bit though.

Comment: Thanks dude... it got worked for me in console application, can you please tell me how to import it based on this export file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm pretty sure [System.Diagnostics.Process.Start()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.start.aspx) would let you run STSADM from .NET code.